# Top Encountered CSS Bugs/Issues

Tags: css

Please list CSS bugs/issues you encounter and how to solve them or a link to a site that solves them.

Please vote on what bugs you think people will encounter the most.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The [Internet Explorer box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

Comment: are people targeting < ie6 still?

Comment: Almost certainly not, but its worth being aware of the issue.

Comment: it occurs in IE6 if you don't specify a doctype, or various other issues that cause IE6 to go into quirks mode, the wikipedia page lists them.

Answer (score 3):

[Double Margin Bug](http://haslayout.net/css/doublemargin)  (< IE7)

Answer (score 2):

IE6 doesn't support min-height.

You can use conditional comments to set height, which IE6 treats as a min-height.

Or you can use the child selector in CSS, which IE6 can't read, to reinstate height: auto on everything but IE6.

```
.myDiv {
height: 100px;
min-height: 100px;
}

.parentElement > .myDiv {
height: auto;
}
```

Using techniques like this can be problematic, but all popular modern browsers work in such a way that it's a valid technique.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every HTML/CSS bug that you will encounter will be in Internet Explorer. IE6 has a lot of them, IE7 a bit fewer and IE8 subtantially fewer.

Having a proper [doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) is a must. Without it the page is rendered in quirks mode, and especially for IE that is bad. It renders the page more or less as IE5 would, with the [box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) and everything.

Here are some common IE bugs:

- Making the content of each element at least one character high. (Can be fixed using overflow.)
- Expanding each element to contain it's children even it it's floating elements. (Can be fixed using overflow.)
- Elements that are not positioned but has layout gets a z-index, although they shouldn't. (Can be fixed by making it positioned and give it a specific z-index, and do the same for all elements on the same level that needs it.)
- Margins are not collapsed correctly. (Use padding instead if possible.)
- Vanishing floating elements. (Give them a specific size.)
- [lots more...](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) (including suggestions for fixes)

The most stable fix for most of the bugs is to rearrange the layout to avoid them, or to specify stricter styles (e.g. a specific size).

Answer (score 1):

Chalk another one up for IE6:
[DropDownList and DIV overlapping problem](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Overlapping.aspx), with screen shots.  The iframe fix is mentioned in the article.  I'm not sure if there are CSS bugs that have consistent buggy behavior across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

here a link that list all IE known bugs and how to fix it:
[PositionsEverything.net](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html)

Answer (score -4):

Rumor has it that IE8 will not allow you to center elements with `text-align: center;`, only the text inside elements themselves. Instead, you must use `margin: 0 auto;`. If this is in fact the case, nearly all of the interwebs will implode.

Comment: Isn't this how things are supposed to be ?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to be, and how all the other browsers work. I have tested this, and I can verify that this bug is corrected in IE8.

Comment: So how is fixing a bug a bug?  O_o

Comment: because most of the websites abuse this feature in IE that allows you to use text-align: center for elements. thanks for the downvotes :P